# On Button Click Validate a template form in Angular 2

Tags: forms, angular, validation, angular2-template

I am new to Angular 2.

I have created a simple template which has two text field, I want to required field validate those two fields.

### Login Form

```
<form #loginForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(loginForm)" novalidate>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="form-group">
            ooooo   <label><b>Username</b></label>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Username" name="uname" required [(ngModel)]="UserData.uname" #uname="ngModel">

            <div *ngIf="loginForm.invalid"  class="alert alert-danger">
                <div [hidden]="!uname.errors.required"> Name is required </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label><b>Password</b></label>
            <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="pwd" required [(ngModel)]="UserData.pwd" #pwd="ngModel">
            <div *ngIf="UserData.pwd.errors && (UserData.pwd.dirty || UserData.pwd.touched)" class="alert alert-danger">
                <div [hidden]="!UserData.pwd.errors.required">Password is required </div>
            </div>
            <button type="submit"  >Login</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

My Component

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core"
import { User } from "./UserModel"


@Component({
    selector: 'my-login',
    templateUrl:"app/Login/login.html"
})

export class LoginComponent
{
    //alert: any("hello");
    UserData: User = new User("", "");

    submitted = false;

    onSubmit(form: any) {
        alert("dfsdfsd" + form);
        if (!form.invalid) {
            alert(this.UserData.uname);
            alert(this.UserData.pwd);
            this.submitted = true;
        }
    }

}
```

What i want to implement is-

1. When the form loads no validation message should appear?
2. When user clicks on the submit button then the required message should appear?
3. In both the textbox i have applied different type of checks to show the message that is inconsistent? so there should be a consistent way to solve this.

Many thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe make use of the `submitted` variable, and use that in template, to not show message, until `submitted` is true, which we set it as in the submit function.

Also you wouldn't really need the two-way-binding here, since the object your form produces is directly assignable to your `UserData`.

The validation messages I'd just set then simply like this, where we are targeting the username:

```
<div *ngIf="uname.errors?.required && submitted"> Name is required </div>
```

in your submit function I'd pass `loginForm.value` as parameter instead of just `loginForm`. This way you get the form object ready to be used :)

And in your function you can assign the object to your `UserData` variable.

```
onSubmit(form: any) {
  this.submitted = true;
  this.UserData = form;
}
```

If you do want to keep the two-way-binding, it's of course totally possible! :)

**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/mHKMcKyZzVPE4jaVqdLH?p=preview)**